# Incorrect padding when I want to connect google sheets with streamlit

Tags: api, google-sheets, base64, cloud, streamlit

I am trying to connect streamlit app to the google sheets as guided by the streamlit community. after running the following part of the code:

```
> scope=[“https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive”,
“https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets”]
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
st.secrets[“gcp_service_account”],
scopes=scope,
)
```

I face the following error.

```
> 2022-08-22 16:03:54.453 Uncaught app exception Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "C:\Users\s.kian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py",
> line 556, in _run_script
>     exec(code, module.__dict__)   File "C:\Users\s.kian\OneDrive - Intrum Law\Desktop\tt\gsh.py", line 11, in <module>
>     credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(   File
> "C:\Users\s.kian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\service_account.py",
> line 221, in from_service_account_info
>     signer = _service_account_info.from_dict(   File "C:\Users\s.kian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\auth\_service_account_info.py",
> line 58, in from_dict
>     signer = crypt.RSASigner.from_service_account_info(data)   File "C:\Users\s.kian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\auth\crypt\base.py",
> line 113, in from_service_account_info
>     return cls.from_string(   File "C:\Users\s.kian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\auth\crypt\_python_rsa.py",
> line 154, in from_string
>     marker_id, key_bytes = pem.readPemBlocksFromFile(   File "C:\Users\s.kian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyasn1_modules\pem.py",
> line 44, in readPemBlocksFromFile
>     substrate = ''.encode().join([base64.b64decode(x.encode()) for x in certLines])   File
> "C:\Users\s.kian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyasn1_modules\pem.py",
> line 44, in <listcomp>
>     substrate = ''.encode().join([base64.b64decode(x.encode()) for x in certLines])   File
> "C:\Users\s.kian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\base64.py",
> line 87, in b64decode
>     return binascii.a2b_base64(s) binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

I searched a lot in the internet, not found anything.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
> scope=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
st.secrets["gcp_service_account"],
scopes=scope,
)
```

no idea what this does or where it goes but maybe the error is from `“` `”` so try replacing it with `"`